# How to switch the user input of time from minutes to an hour?

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

I am trying to create a countdown timer that counts down from an hour if a user enters 1 or 2 hours if a user enters 2, etc.. I know I need to multiply the value I am getting from the user by 60 in order to switch from calculating minutes and seconds from the input to calculating by hour but I am just not quite sure where to do so.

```
   <script>
    function startTimer() {
      userInput = document.getElementById('userTime').value;
        if(userInput.length == 0){
        alert("Please enter a value");
        } else {
        var numericExpression = /^[0-9]+$/;
        if(!userInput.match(numericExpression)){
        alert("Please enter a number")
        } else {

       function display( notifier, str ) {
        document.getElementById(notifier).innerHTML = str;
      }

      function toMinuteAndSecond( x ) {
        return Math.floor(x/60) + ":" + x%60;
      }

      function setTimer( remain, actions ) {
        (function countdown() {
           display("countdown", toMinuteAndSecond(remain));         
           actions[remain] && actions[remain]();
           (remain -= 1) >= 0 && setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
        })();
      }

      setTimer(userInput, {
        10: function () { display("notifier", "Warning message 1",    document.bgColor="#ffff00"); },
         5: function () { display("notifier", "Warning message 2", document.bgColor="#ff69b4");        },
         0: function () { display("notifier", "Final message", document.bgColor="#ff0000");       }
      }); 
    }  
    }
    }

    </script>

    <div id="countdown"></div>
    <div id="notifier"></div>
    <p>
    Please Enter A Time Limit for the Meeting: <input type="text" id="userTime" />
    <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="startTimer()" />
    </p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you really need to change is your `toMinuteAndSecond` function, which I have renamed and done below:

```
userInput = document.getElementById('userTime').value;
if (userInput.length == 0) {
    alert("Please enter a value");
} else {
    var numericExpression = /^[0-9]+$/;
    if (!userInput.match(numericExpression)) {
        alert("Please enter a number")
    } else {

        function display(notifier, str) {
            document.getElementById(notifier).innerHTML = str;
        }

        function toFormattedHHMMSS(x) {
            var hours = parseInt(x / 3600);
            var minutes = parseInt(x / 60) % 60;
            var seconds = x % 60;

            return (hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours) + ":" + (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes) + ":" + (seconds  < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds);
        }

        function setTimer(remain, actions) {
            (function countdown() {
                display("countdown", toFormattedHHMMSS(remain));
                actions[remain] && actions[remain]();
                (remain -= 1) >= 0 && setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
            })();
        }

        setTimer(userInput, {
            10: function () {
                display("notifier", "Warning message 1", document.bgColor = "#ffff00");
            },
            5: function () {
                display("notifier", "Warning message 2", document.bgColor = "#ff69b4");
            },
            0: function () {
                display("notifier", "Final message", document.bgColor = "#ff0000");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The same would be done for allowing days, or weeks, etc...

Comment: This gets me a lot closer- thank you so much Ryan! However, I want to make it so if a user enters 1 in the input field it will convert it to 60 minutes on the timer. The user still has to type the amount of time they want in seconds.

Comment: @user3440038 Oh I see, in the second else statement just do a userInput = userInput * 60; This way we have already made sure there has been a value entered, and it is a number.

Comment: OMG! It's working the way I want it to! Your suggestion worked - You rock!! Thank you so, so much. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

seems like allot more code than needed to simply count down. Of course I don't know the broader aspects of your implementation but nonetheless I'm a big fan of getting to the point and reducing the complexity of code.

A simple start point is that you can reduce all of this:

```
if (userInput.length == 0) {
    alert("Please enter a value");
} else {
    var numericExpression = /^[0-9]+$/;
    if (!userInput.match(numericExpression)) {
        alert("Please enter a number")
    } else {
```

to this:

```
if ((+userInput > 0) !== true) {alert("Please enter a valid time"); return;}
```

And here's an example of cutting the whole thing back:

```
<script>
    function startTimer() {
        var t = document.getElementById('userTime').value;
        if ((+t > 0) !== true) {alert("Please enter a valid time in hours"); return;}
        t = parseFloat(t, 10) * 3600; //convert hours & fractions of hours to seconds
        countDown(t);
    }

    function countDown(t) {
        if ((t - 1) > 0) setTimeout(function(){countDown(t - 1); }, 1000);
        printTime(t-1);
    }

    function printTime(t) {
        var e = document.getElementById("countdown");
        e.innerHTML = (t == 0) ? "Times up!" : Math.floor(t / 60) + ":" + t % 60;
        e.style.color = (t < 300) ? "#ff0" : (t < 600) ? "#ff69b4" : "#000";
    }
</script>
```

Now to build in better formatting, more user messages, warnings etc you only need to work on the printTime(t) function.